# how to convert php echo to alert in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [Plugin](http://duncanheron.github.io/dropPin/) to add a marker to a image but they are in php echo formats but i want to get them as java script alert method or as a div to print using JavaScript ..

Code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#map').dropPin('showPin',{
            fixedHeight:495,
            fixedWidth:700,
            backgroundImage: '/images/{some-image.jpg}',
            pin: '/image/{custom-pin-graphic.png}'
            pinX: <?php echo {pinXcoord} ?>,
            pinY: <?php echo {pinYcoord} ?>
            });
    });
</script>
```

i try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').dropPin('showPin',{
        fixedHeight:495,
        fixedWidth:700,
        backgroundImage: '/images/{some-image.jpg}',
        pin: '/image/{custom-pin-graphic.png}'
        pinX: alert(pinXcoord),
        pinY: alert(pinYcoord)
        });
});
</script>
```

but i can"t get the value

Comment: *but i can"t get the value* Do you mean that your code is working, but the values of `pinXcoord` and `pinYcoord` are undefined?

Comment: I don't see those variables being defined anywhere - are they supposed to be variables in your php?

Comment: wanted to remove that php echo statement to normal JavaScript alert

Comment: But what are `pinXcoord` and `pinYcoord`? Are they variables in your PHP? (if so, you're not referring to them correctly because PHP variables are formatted `$likeThis`)

Comment: @RamanaaGj: `"wanted to remove that php echo statement"` - If they're *PHP* variables (are they?  they seem to be missing a `$`) then you would need to use them *in PHP code*.  If you want to use variables in Javascript then you have to define them in JavaScript.  Also, that use of `alert()` in building an object looks... strange.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: These variables are server side php variables. And you can get them only through php. You cannot use them as normal JS variables.

Comment: sorry i am new to js . clearly i am not using php any more but i want to display it as alert is there any way to get those variables as a js alert method or not ?

Comment: @RamanaaGj: First you have to *define* those variables in your JavaScript and *set some value to them*.  Variables work the same in JavaScript as they do in PHP.  You declare the variable, assign a value to it, and use it.  So far you're just trying to use it, you skipped the first steps.  There is no way to use a variable which doesn't exist, in JavaScript or in any other language.

Comment: @RamanaaGj: I just saw the dropPin page. Those are not any predefined variables. You are supposed to define them in php. If you want echo format. If you want them as JS, define them as JS variables. They are not library variables!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = <?php echo {pinXcoord} ?>;
    var y = <?php echo {pinXcoord} ?>;
    $('#map').dropPin('showPin',{
        fixedHeight:495,
        fixedWidth:700,
        backgroundImage: '/images/{some-image.jpg}',
        pin: '/image/{custom-pin-graphic.png}'
        pinX: x,
        pinY: y
        });
    alert(x+" "+y);
});
</script>
```

Comment: wanted to remove that php echo statement and normal JavaScript alert

Comment: php echo is not a format. It is a server side code that is passing the data to your front end JS. Those variables are not defined in JS, you can get them only by using php. So if you want to have them in the alert. This is the only way

Comment: yes how to defined those variables as js variables and to get it as an alert is there any way ?

Comment: Thats what I have written in my answer

Comment: @RamanaaGj: You define a JavaScript variable with the `var` keyword.  Something like: `var x = "some value";`  Since it's a dynamic language, you can store any value you want in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming that you have the php variables($pinXcoord, $pinYcoord) defined in the same page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').dropPin('showPin',{
        fixedHeight:495,
        fixedWidth:700,
        backgroundImage: '/images/{some-image.jpg}',
        pin: '/image/{custom-pin-graphic.png}'
        pinX: '<?php echo $pinXcoord; ?>',
        pinY: '<?php echo $pinYcoord ?>'
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: wanted to remove that php echo statement to normal JavaScript alert

Comment: You want those values to be displayed in an alert? Aren't you supposed to pass them as values for pinX and pinY so that it would point a pin at that location coordinates??